# Not able to print raise notice output in log file tried with all log conditions - SET client_min_messages TO debug1;

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

```
BEGIN

    RAISE INFO    'raise info    - time: %', now() ;
    RAISE WARNING 'raise warning - time: %', now();
    RAISE NOTICE  'raise notice  - time: %', now();
    RAISE LOG     'raise log     - time: %', now();
    RAISE DEBUG   'raise debug   - time: %', now();
    raise notice ' SPR:  % %',V_H2,REPORT_DT;
    raise notice ' SPR: Others%',V_H1;
end;

SET client_min_messages TO debug1;
```

Is not working with debug1

Comment: In Oracle we have DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line it will print the output in Log file but in postgres it will not work. in Log file I am getting only "Do"

Comment: Which SQL client are you using?

Comment: Please describe exactly what you are doing. The order of statements in your question looks wrong.

Comment: I am running psql code using putty. Raise notice result need to store in log file but while running code in begin end it will reflect code in log file . It wil return only Do

Answer (score 1):

It is working on my comp (executed from `psql`)

```
(2022-05-12 12:04:34) postgres=# SET client_min_messages TO debug1; 
SET
(2022-05-12 12:04:47) postgres=# do $$                              
BEGIN

    RAISE INFO    'raise info    - time: %', now() ;
    RAISE WARNING 'raise warning - time: %', now();
    RAISE NOTICE  'raise notice  - time: %', now();
    RAISE LOG     'raise log     - time: %', now();
    RAISE DEBUG   'raise debug   - time: %', now();
end;
$$;
INFO:  raise info    - time: 2022-05-12 12:04:48.75055+02
WARNING:  raise warning - time: 2022-05-12 12:04:48.75055+02
NOTICE:  raise notice  - time: 2022-05-12 12:04:48.75055+02
LOG:  raise log     - time: 2022-05-12 12:04:48.75055+02
DEBUG:  raise debug   - time: 2022-05-12 12:04:48.75055+02
DO
```

Comment: Its working but its not printing result in log file like if I am giving \o \tmp\Logfile.log  it should be printed on that file.  it is printing only Do

Comment: @SamirMjs - you should to set log_min_messages https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN

Comment: I have tried that one also by setting log_min_messages but still it not working

Comment: @SamirMjs - I rechecked it now, and it is working on my computer. Maybe you use too old postgres, maybe you check bad log file.